# RuntimeError on declaring Reference to other MLM

Tags: compiler-construction, declaration, mlm, arden-syntax

[image: RuntimeError]

It appears the compiler doesn't recognize the single tic at the end of the line to end the MLM name.
After testing different scenarios, I learned, the only tic recognized is the last in the data segment.
How can I declare multiple MLM and V`variables?

Comment: Please follow the [contribtuion guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how to ask a good question. Please don't post images of code and error messages.